# The impulse response of the Rayleigh-Sommerfeld formulation of diffraction

Tags: optics, diffraction

What is the impulse response for the Rayleigh-Sommerfeld formulation of diffraction? In Goodman's Fourier Optics, *two* formulations for Rayleigh-Sommerfeld are given, and both of them seem to be equally valid. I know that for Fresnel diffraction, the impulse response is given by
$$\frac{\exp(jkz)}{j\lambda z}\exp\left(j\frac{k}{2z}(x^2+y^2)\right) , $$
where $(x,y,z)$ is the point $(x,y)$ on the propagation plane at distance $z$ from the aperture plane and the transfer function is simply the Fourier inverse of this. However I am not sure what the impulse response would be for the Rayleigh-Sommerfeld formulation.

Goodman derives both Rayleigh-Sommerfeld diffraction integrals and then goes on to discuss the Huygens-Fresnel principle, where an 'impulse response' is defined as
$$\frac{1}{j\lambda}\frac{\exp(jkr_{01})}{r_{01}}\cos\theta . $$ Is this the impulse response for the Rayleigh-Sommerfeld formulation? I do not think so, because, [this](https://spie.org/samples/PM103.pdf) link says that the impulse response is
$$ \frac{1}{\lambda}\left(\frac{1}{kl_0}-i\right)\frac{z}{l_0}\frac{\exp(ikl_0)}{l_0}, $$
which, when converted to Goodman's notation, should be
$$ \frac{1}{\lambda}\left(\frac{1}{kr_{01}}-j\right)\frac{z}{r_{01}}\frac{\exp(jkr_{01})}{r_{01}} . $$

How do I solve this?